# position not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to move a div to one side or the other depending on it's position, BUT! no matter what method I use to chance its position, it doesn't really change.

```
var $ancho = $(document).width();
var $posP = $("#portafolio").offset().left;
var $porP = Math.floor($posP * 100 / $ancho);
```

the var porP saves the percentage of the div's (portafolio) position

Now, the initial position of portafolio is 13(%)

```
if($porP == '13')
  {


    $("#portafolio").mouseenter(function(){
            $("#imge").stop().fadeTo('500', 0.3,  function() {});});

        $("#portafolio").mouseleave(function(){
            $("#imge").stop().fadeOut('500',  function() {});
            });

    $("#portafolio").click(function(){

      $("#portafolio").animate({
        left: "+=87%",}, 
        { queue: false, duration: 900, easing:'swing' }); 
         $("#imge").fadeTo('500', 0.3,  function() {

             });

        $(iframe).attr('src','portafolio.html');
        $("#marco").fadeTo('500', 1 ,  function() {});
         $(iframe).open();


      });


  }
```

but even when I move portafolio to the right, in the animation function, the porP var still shows 13, therefore it never reaches the else

```
else
  { move to the other side }
```

I already tried to assign a new value to the porP var inside the click function but to no avail. It just always executes the IF statement.

Does someone know why the value (porP) doesn't change? and how can I actually change it to make the else finally work?
I searched everywhere and tried everything that came to my mind with my very limited knowledge of jquery and got to nowhere. Please!!

edit//  `#portafolio` is a relative positioned div to its parent `#contenido` which is absolute positioned and is `left 20px` . `#portafolio` is left 15% . I don't know if that has something to do.

Comment: Have you tried alerting/console-ing the value of porP to see that you are getting what you need.

Comment: yeah, it always gave me 13 or whatever value it got from the `&posP`

Comment: Alice, did you try my suggestion? I edited it so it updates $porP each time there's a click.

Answer (score 0):

Alice, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but the *if* and *else* statements probably should be inside the 'click()' handler. Something like,

```
$("#portafolio").click(function(){

var $ancho = $(document).width();
var $posP = $("#portafolio").offset().left;
var $porP = Math.floor($posP * 100 / $ancho);

if($porP == '13')
{

  $("#portafolio").animate({
    left: "+=87%",}, 
    { queue: false, duration: 900, easing:'swing' }); 
     $("#imge").fadeTo('500', 0.3,  function() {

         });

    $(iframe).attr('src','portafolio.html');
    $("#marco").fadeTo('500', 1 ,  function() {});
     $(iframe).open();

}
else
{ move to the other side }

});
```